# How Can I send sms confirmation when user creates a new account in my website?

Tags: users, status-messages

Can I send sms confirmation when user creates a new account in my website?

How Can I? what modules I have to set for this?

Answer (score 1):

[Rules](https://www.drupal.org/project/rules) module will allow you to do something when something happens in the system. You can send email or sms when an account is created. This is a very handy module, you should have it.

In regards to SMS, there are a few options.

1. [SMS Framework](https://www.drupal.org/project/smsframework) module
2. [Messaging](https://www.drupal.org/project/messaging) module
3. [VoIP Drupal](https://www.drupal.org/project/voipdrupal) module

In regards to the SMS framework, I don't know how stable is the 7.x development release. You need to make some decisions here.

There are a tons of video/other tutorials on how to use Rules module, I recommend googling it and you will come across several sources. Do try the free videos provided by DruaplizeMe, they are very useful.

Comment: do you suggest any free SMS Framework for testing?

Comment: @SatheeshKammathR No, we don't recommend 3rd party services here as they're nothing to do with Drupal

Comment: @SatheeshKammathR if I were you, I would go through those modules, read the documentations, see the list of bugs/issues (open/fixed) and then decide which one to use. You can also find more information and tutorials by googling the module.

Answer (score 0):

For doing some action on user creation you have to implement 
[hook_user_insert](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules!user!user.api.php/function/hook_user_insert/7) or you may use [rules](https://www.drupal.org/project/rules) module.

For sending SMS from your site you can use [SMS Framework](https://www.drupal.org/project/smsframework) or Use Third Party SMS service.